# Preview files in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-community

When i preview file in lightning experience its provides me multiple option for eg - share the document.
but when i preview the document in lightning community portal.
its doesn't show me share option.
in lightning experience
[image]

in community portal

[image]

can anyone tell me if this is limitation.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as per design.

> ## [Lightning File Preview Player Now Available in Communities](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_file_previewer.htm)
>
> ...
>
> Want to do more than just preview your file? All your actions are right there in the preview window. Upload a new version, delete, download, and view file details. You can get it all done in one place.